# how to delegate this functionality properly in OOP

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for a project and I have a couple of questions about the proper way of designing the implementation.

I have a "Deal" class that basically holds the attributes of a deal like the name, the expiration, the deal description and etc.

On top of that, I also have a "Campaign" class that deals with the external stuff related to a deal, but not really tied to it.  For example, a campaign could contain the header and footer image, the theme that the deal will be rendered into and so on.  A campaign can only have one deal at a time and the same thing goes for the deal.  Once a deal expires, another deal could be tied to the same campaign.

The data for both "Deals" and "Campaign" comes from their own separate model classes (DealsModel and CampaignModel).

Because I wanted the controller to only call one class to setup the campaign and deal for the view, I created an intermediate class called ViewManager that creates the appropriate logic and massages the data from both the "Deals" class and "Campaign" before it sends it to the controller who hands it back to the view.

Now, I have some functions in the controller that needs to have direct access to the model class.  I am wondering if I should delegate this functionality to the ViewManager class and let it handle it since it has an instance of the model or should I create a new instance of the model in the controller and call it directly.

It just feels like the more I delegate functions to the ViewManager, the more confusing the code is turning out to be.

Answer (score 1):

This all sounds like a bad implementation of MVC. Especially the Model part.

From what you have described, it looks like both `Deals` and `Campaign` classes are actually a merge of [Domain Object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) and Data Access Object. They are structures which should be used by [Domain Model](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainModel). And this domain model should contain that additional functionality.

The whole issue comes from mis-implementation of MVC which is presented in CodeIgniter. ActiveRecord is not a sufficient replacement for a real Model. This mistake forces the business logic into Controller and even into View. I blame RoR.

P.S .. oh .. and class names like Managare are usually considered to be a *code smell*.